# retrieve number of open activities from owning case

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics

I have a number of case detail entities which all have different case resolutions dependent on the type.  On selection of a case resolution type I can make the detail form inactive and call a child workflow to make the owning case resolved.  However if the owning case has open activities then of course it will not be resolved.  Is there a way I can retrieve the number of open activities from an owning case and therefore use in my workflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Workflow doesn't support aggregate functions such as count so you would need to add some logic to maintain a count of open activities on the parent case.  The best way I can think of to maintain the activity count on the case would be to write a plugin that runs on post-create/post-changestate/pre-delete of activities that checks to see if they are regarding a case and if so, does a RetrieveMultiple request to the CRM web services to count the number of total activities that belong to the parent case, then update a custom activity count field on the parent case (via web services) with the total number of activities.

Once you have done that you will be able to use the parent cases activity count in your case workflows.  You will incur a performance hit with this since the web service calls will require a little time, especially on the deletes since they must run synchronously prior to the delete occurring.  It is likely that deletes will not occur very commonly since you probably want to track your closed activities.  Depending on your needs you can probably set up the post plugins to run asynchronously and you will not see a direct performance hit for those, but you will have to wait for the async plugins to fire much like workflows.  If designed right you can accomplish all of this with one plugin, with 3 steps (1 for each event).